# Рекурсивный вывод числа наоборот

Tags: java, рекурсия

Есть задача, написать рекурсивную процедуру для вывода на экран цифр натурального числа в обратном порядке. Я её решил, но хочу что бы на выходе из рекурсии получалось целое число. Вот, что я сейчас имею.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int consoleInputFirstNumber() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            return scan.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entered not number. Try again.");
            return consoleInputFirstNumber();
        }
    }

    public static void numberReverseOrder(int number) {
        if (number == 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.print(number % 10);
            numberReverseOrder(number / 10);
        }
    }

    public static void consoleOutput(int result) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = consoleInputFirstNumber();
        numberReverseOrder(input);
    }
}
```

Кто знает, что нужно что бы решить мою проблему дайте подсказку или напишите решение. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что, сейчас не целое число выводится?

Comment: Мне нужно было число которое являлось бы зеркальным отражением, тому числу, которое поступило на вход в рекурсивный метод. Пример - пользователь ввёл 345 это число передаётся в рекурсивный метод, а при выполнении условия выхода из рекурсии, я получал число 543 и мог с ним работать дальше.

Comment: Всё равно не понятно, что вам нужно. Вы уже решили задачу? Если да, то опубликуйте ответ и выберите его правильным. Если нет, то попробуйте яснее выразиться. Число 345 - не зеркальное число. Пожалуйста, ясно напишите, в чём ваша проблема и что вы хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: Решение ниже. В следующий раз попробую изъясняться лучше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то ваша программа вроде как работает. Она только для `0` ничего не выводит, поэтому непонятно, чего вы хотите. Но вот для разнообразия моё решение.

Проще такую задачу решать, преобразовав число в строку и сведя её к выводу перевёрнутой строки. Кроме того я бы разделил преобразование строки к перевёрнутой и собственно вывод. Вот как вашу задачу можно решить рекурсивно:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursiveReverse {
    public static String reverse(String str) {
        return str.isEmpty() ? "" : reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            System.out.println("Reversed: " + reverse(String.valueOf(scan.nextInt())));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот мой простой ответ:

```
static int reverse(int num){
    return num<10 ?num:Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num%10)+reverse(num/10));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без использования строки. Класс IntRef нужен для имитации передачи параметра по ссылке.

```
public class RecursiveReverse {

    private static class IntRef {
        int value;

        public IntRef( int value ) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static int reverse( int arg ) {
        IntRef result = new IntRef( 0 );
        reverseRec( arg, 1, new IntRef( 0 ), result);

        return result.value;
    }

    private static void reverseRec( int arg, int curDepth, IntRef maxDepth, IntRef result ) {
        if ( arg < 10 ) {
            maxDepth.value = curDepth;
            result.value = arg;
        } else {
            reverseRec( arg/10, curDepth * 10, maxDepth, result );
            result.value = result.value + (arg % 10) * maxDepth.value / curDepth;
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int[] tests = new int[] { 0, 1, 5, 10, 11, 15, 100, 123, 555, 375, 1000, 1040, 12345 };

        for ( int test : tests ) {
            System.out.printf( "%6d | %d%n", test, reverse( test ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересный и полезный вариант, во всяком случае для моего уровня знания языка =)

Answer (score 0):

Решение на c# (без рекурсивно, но быстро и это решения не только для натуральных чисел, работает для целых чисел;
например для х=123 результат 321, если х=-324 то, результат -423):

```
public int Reverse(int x) {
       var sign = x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            long result = 0;            
            x = x * sign;
            while (x >= 10)
            {
                var tmp = x % 10;
                result = result * 10 + tmp;
                x = x / 10;
            }
            result = sign*(result * 10 + x);
            if (result > int.MaxValue || result < int.MinValue)
                return 0;

            return (int) result;
    }
```